# For RSA encryption, finding d given p,q, and e?

Tags: encryption, rsa

**How would I find `d` given `p = 7, q = 11, e = 3`?**

There are many similar questions to this, but they ask you to calculate your own e. This would be a trivial solution if `e = 11` or `e = 17`, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with `e = 3` specifically.

My understanding goes:

d = e<sup>-1</sup>mod(p-1)(q-1)

d = 3<sup>-1</sup>mod(6)(10)

d * 3 == 1 mod 60

However this leads to 3 not being invertible mod 60, as 3 is not relatively prime to 60. Is there a solution given this value of e=3? Thank you for any help.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but yes RSA requires e coprime to p-1 and q-1 (or equivalently phi(N) or lambda(N)). See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/in-rsa-why-is-it-important-to-choose-e-so-that-it-is-coprime- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31237/public-key-exponent-coprime-with-totient-proof https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20324/is-there-a-way-to-systematically-calculate- and maybe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/why-does-choosing-the-first-coprime-e-greater-than-half-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering the question in the title). In my algorithms, i use this:

```
d =(1+(z* ϕ(N)))/e
```

The private key d has to be an integer so `z` should start at `1` and be incremented by `1` until it is an integer. 
`ϕ(N)` is Euler's totient function.

```
ϕ(N) = (p-1)*(q-1)
```

EDIT: When I insert these primes into my code I get `e = 7`.

To find `e`correctly: `e` has to be a number where the greatest common divisor of `e` and `ϕ(N)` is equal to 1.

So `e` starts at `1` and is incremented by `1` until the greatest common divisor is also `1`.

Comment: This is the right answer; my professor had made a typo and corrected with e=7. Then using extended Euclid, d=43. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote that e starts at 1 and then increments until the gcd is 1. Does that mean e can only be 7, or can other coprime values be valid?

Comment: The original approach to RSA was pick random `p` and `q`, pick any `d` which is relatively prime to `phi(n)` (GCD==1), produce `e`  (https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf sec VII (C)).  Now it's pick `e` arbitrarily as probably `0x010001`, pick random `p` and `q`, derive `d`; if it didn't work, pick a new `p` and `q`... because it makes the public key operations faster.

Comment: Also, FWIW, the "best" answer for `d` is 0x0D.  But 43 is valid, and it took a while before anyone observed 0x0D was better; maybe your class will cover that at a later date :).

Comment: @PaulChoi other values can be valid, for example, you could make `e = 8` and then increment it.

Answer (score 1):

My calculator says there's no solution.  (All values base 10)

- `n` = `p * q` = `77`
- `phi(n)` = `(p-1) * (q-1)` = `60`
- Attempt to compute `ModInv(3, 60)` and realize there's no solution because 3 divides 60 evenly.

Just for kicks I re-ran it with "assume inputs are (sensibly) in hexadecimal", making `q=17`, and it's also not solvable, because `phi(n)` is 96, which is also evenly divisible by 3.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Turns out my professor just made a typo and corrected with e=7